# C variable allocation using macro

Tags: c, embedded, iar

I want to allocate value to variable using macro by user.

```
#define  CountA  3
#define  A0      0x01
#define  A1      0x02
#define  A2      0x03
```

CountA definition differs per application and A0, A1, ..., An also differs per application. i,e. That is not my own code. It is a part of user code for using my core.

```
#define MakeDefinitionA(n)    A##(n)  


unsigned char n;
unsigned char data[CountA];
unsigned char cnt;

cnt = 0;
for (n = 0; n < (unsigned char)CountA; n++) {
  data[cnt++] = MakeDefinitionA(n);
}
```

Finally, I want to get data value from user code like this.

How can I do? What should I modify that code?

Comment: "Defined values are above" - No. These are the macro definitions.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean. And why not just use the macros directly? Too obvious? Too readable? Too short to write?

Comment: `MakeDefinitionA(n);` preprocessor can't use(evaluate) run-time variable.

Comment: Ok, I got it. Please read when macros are evaluated. They are textual replacements. C is not a dynamic language. What do you want to accomplish? Why not use an array? So little code, so many questions ...

Comment: Do you mean yoy want to have the preprocessor interpret (something like) a `for` loop?

Comment: "How can I do?" One way is using another language. You may have to build your own compiler or interpreter.

Comment: Do you know how macros work and what they do?

Comment: The definitions are in option.h file for users that use my code. And, other codes are core code that is not for users. I want to handle option file by users and core code always working along with user option.

Answer (score 0):

use `boost/preprocessor` like this

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/cat.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/repetition/repeat_from_to.hpp>

#define DECL(z, n, text) BOOST_PP_CAT(text, n),

#define  CountA  3
#define  A0      0x01
#define  A1      0x02
#define  A2      0x03


int main() {
    unsigned char n;
    unsigned char data[CountA] = { BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO(0, CountA, DECL, A) };
    unsigned char cnt = CountA;

}
```

expand to

```
int main() {
        unsigned char n;
        unsigned char data[3] = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, };
        unsigned char cnt = 3;

}
```

Comment: That's would be interesting to see how boost does it.  I can think of a very ugly way to do it with __counter__ and recursive #includes terminated with  #if __counter__ != terminus, but it sounds like an ugly, ugly hack.

Comment: This question was never tagged C++. Boost will not be available on an embedded systems C compiler.

Comment: @Lundin `boost/preprocessor` can use for C.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Which embedded systems C compiler supports it then? I've never heard of one.

Comment: But also I never heard even such constraints.　E.g c preprocessor(cpp) can be used alone.

Comment: Looks like massive overkill, just to make an array initializer.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use macros. Simply use an enum and a table:

```
typedef enum
{
  A0 = 0x01,
  A1 = 0x02,
  A2 = 0x03,
} A_t;

const A_t LIST [] =
{
  A0,
  A1,
  A2
};

#define CountA ( sizeof(LIST)/sizeof(*LIST) )


int main( void )
{
  unsigned char data[CountA];
  unsigned char cnt;


  for (size_t i = 0; i < CountA; i++) {
    data[i] = LIST[i];
  }  

  cnt = CountA;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `enum is not used anywhere else, you why not just provide the array initialiser? Also `enum`s can have varying sizes, but OP might want a specific/minimal size (this is tagged `embedded`).

Comment: @Olaf Because it seems like the OP wants a distinct type. Also the more common way to declare such enums is `typedef enum { A0, A1, A2, A_N } A_t;` is which case you can statically assert the array size against `A_N`, to ensure that the table is correct. If the size is a concern, you might have to use `typedef uint8_t A_t` instead. 3 bytes of flash vs 6 bytes of flash is probably not an issue though...

Comment: (Sorry for the malformatted text; saw it too late) For 3 entrries that might be correct (although it could well be 12 bytes on a 32 bit platform), but who knows OP or another reader will not have hundreds of values? If it is about a distinct type, just `typedef short init_array_type;` would be sufficient, the size can be calculated by the macro you already use (imo the better approach). The `enum`s plus array just add redundancy. If it is for a simple incremental sequence, there is not even need for an array. Just my 2ct.

Answer (score 0):

@Lundin's suggestion to use enums makes for very efficient code, but I have found that method difficult to maintain once the lists go beyond a half page or so.  That is why I adapted this method:

```
#define TAG_MAP { \ 
   _MAP(TAG_BODY,"body"), \ 
   _MAP(TAG_HEAD,"head"), \ 
   _MAP(TAG_HTML,"html"), \ 
   _MAP(TAG_UNKNOWN,"unknown"), \ 
} 

#define _MAP(x,y) x 
enum tags TAG_MAP; 
#undef _MAP 
#define _MAP(x,y) y 
const char *tagstrings[] = TAG_MAP; 
#undef _MAP 
//usage: printf("%s\n",tagstrings[TAG_HTML]);
```

This method can be used to initialize your `data[]` directly, which is basically a more efficient version of what a macro version of a `for(;;)` loop would do (you can't dereference the value of a variable for pasting in a macro)

This can be extended to as many elements of any type as you like and even multiple arguments (if you put them last and use `,...` and `__VA_ARGS__`)  I use it often to keep a sorted list that can resolve to an enum using a quick binary search and then use that value for various lookup tables.

For a more complex example that uses macros only and also uses **VA_ARGS** see [my quixotic libc](https://github.com/technosaurus/BQC/blob/master/bqc.h#L977)
All of the architecture dependent stuff is defined on 1 line and various preprocessor directives map each nth argument to the appropriate definition.
The syscalls use another kind of hack to call sycall0 ... syscall6 depending on the number of arguments passed.